# Clear input fields on form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I know this is continuously asked anew, and I've checked out different answers and tried different solutions but to no avail. In some cases it can be really be a case by case thing depending on how the code has been redacted.

I'd like to simply have the two input fields in my page to clear when I click submit (&& enter - unless its a separate event, that's for another thread), considering I always press enter as opposed to clicking - this is a site just meant for my use.

I have of course a input tag, type submit, and its working fine. But I also already have a specific onSubmit function :

```
function onSubmitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var var1 = document.getElementById("name");
    var var2 = document.getElementById("review");
    arrayOne.push( {name:var1.value,review:var2.value} );
    localStorage.filmDatabase = JSON.stringify(arrayOne);
    document.getElementById("eyedee").innerHTML += '<p>' + '<span class=name>' + var1.value + '</span>' + '<span class=review>' + var2.value + '</span>';
}
```

I'm guessing its just about putting one line of (right) code, most probably at the end of the block but I just couldn't figure it out. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You should using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)..Why? see [this](http://blog.utest.com/why-should-anyone-use-jquery/2011/06/)

Comment: along the same lines of the initial question, still with the same onSubmitForm method, how do I get the focus to be set back to the "first" input field on submit, to get it "ready" for immediate form re-entry without having to select it each time. Thnx!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use the [reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/form.reset) function, which is available on the form element.

```
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
form.reset();
```

Answer (score 42):

You can clear out their values by just setting value to an empty string:

```
var1.value = '';
var2.value = '';
```

Comment: Thanks ! =) This was the final option I went for as it was easier for me to integrate into the code ^^ thanks to all ! =)

Comment: very clean and easy.

Answer (score 6):

You can access the form over the event:

```
e.target.reset();
```

Comment: easiest way. Works in react as well.
If it's not a form but an input,
`e.target.value = ''`

Answer (score 2):

By this way, you hold a form by his ID and throw all his content.
This technic is fastiest.

```
document.forms["id_form"].reset();
```

Answer (score 2):

Still using empty strings you can use:

```
document.getElementById("name").value = '';
document.getElementById("review").value = '';
```